# Making a new numpy array from numpy array

Tags: numpy, image-processing

Very new to numpy arrays. Trying to learn more about them and get over the confusion.

I have a numpy array with 50 1000x1000 images. Shape is (50,1000,1000). I want to flip each image and put it in the a new numpy array with shape (50,1000,1000).

This works, but is there an easier way without using an intermediate list?

```
images = []
for index in range(training_images.shape[0]):
    image = training_images[index,...]
    flipped = np.fliplr(image)
    images.append(flipped)
flipped_training_images = np.concatenate([np.expand_dims(x,axis=0) for x in images],axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flip along the last axis -

```
flipped_training_images = training_images[...,::-1]
```

Note that this would be a view. So, if a copy is needed, append `.copy()` with it.

As such, we can use [`np.flip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) as well :

```
np.flip(training_images,axis=-1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry but my version doesn't have np.flip.

How would I do a flip on the horizontal axis?

Comment: @lr100 Did you try the first one : `training_images[...,::-1]` ? What 's the feedback on it? What is horizontal axis?

Comment: I did. I looks like that one does the flip on the horizontal axis. I tried training_images[...,:-1:] but that didn't seem to work. Sorry I am really new to this.

Comment: @lr100 You might be looking to get a copy. So, as mentioned try : `flipped_training_images = training_images[...,::-1].copy()`. This produces exactly the same result as in your loopy version.

Comment: Ya, your code works great. I was also trying to flip over the horizontal axis.